# What is a chemical daily life experience that can be modelled by superior mathematics?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

I'm searching for a chemical daily life experience that can be modelled by superior mathematics so that the origin of the equations involved can be easily explained to a beginner in chemistry.

By superior mathematics I mean things like partial and ordinary differential equation, Integral Calculus, group theory, differential geometry. But I want to understand how are the equations derived.

For example, in physics, I could model the trajectory of the rear wheel of a bicycle (a daily life experience) and I fully understand all the equations involved, without being a physicist. I want something similar to find in chemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diffusion is one example from the daily life. For example, the absorption of ethanol from the small intestine to blood can be modeled using differential equations. The extraction of caffeine from grounded coffee is also a diffusion phenomenon.